# Moodle: Invalid parameter exception

Tags: moodle

I'm trying to make a

```
http://domain.com/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=4725a345345435342322a6560b068547297748e17&wsfunction=mod_forum_get_forum_discussions_paginated
```

with post data:

```
{
    "forumid":2438
}
```

Headers:

```
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
```

But I get the error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<EXCEPTION class="invalid_parameter_exception">
<ERRORCODE>invalidparameter</ERRORCODE>
<MESSAGE>Invalid parameter value detected</MESSAGE>
</EXCEPTION>
```

I have my moodle session as a cookie. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try putting forumid in the url?

http://domain.com/webservice/rest/server.php?forumid=2438&wstoken=4725a345345435342322a6560b068547297748e17&wsfunction=mod_forum_get_forum_discussions_paginated

https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-46458